# How can I get grails to persist a list of objects in a class?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following:

**GroupMember.groovy**

```
public class GroupMember{
  String userName
  String role
}
```

**GroupProfile.groovy**

```
public class GroupProfile{
  List<GroupMember> groupMembers = new ArrayList<GroupMember>()
}
```

**GroupProfileController.groovy**

```
public class GroupProfileController{
  def createProfile{
    GroupMember groupOwner = new GroupMember()
    groupOwner.userName = "testUser"
    groupOwner.role = "OWNER"
    groupOwner.save()

    GroupProfile groupProfile = new GroupProfile()
    def members = grouProfile.groupMembers
    members.add(groupOwner)
    groupProfile.save()

    GroupProfile.list() //This list contains my GroupMember instance with the correct info
    redirecT(action: myProfiles)
  }

  def myProfiles={
    GroupProfile.list() //This list contains my groupProfile that I made but no GroupMember info
  }
}
```

My `GroupProfile` won't save my `GroupMember` info.  How can I get my `GroupProfile` to save the `GroupMember` info?

Comment: Why not just using grails `hasMany` ? [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to represent this relationship in grails would be:

```
public class GroupProfile {
    static hasMany = [groupMembers: GroupMember]
}
```

This will automatically generate a method on `GroupProfile` called `addToGroupMembers` that will create the associations.  Saving the `GroupProfile` will also cascade to the group members, so you'll only need to call save once after adding the members.

Note that the `groupMembers` collection will actually be an instance of `Set` that doesn't necessarily preserve order.  You can explicitly declare the collection as a `List` to preserve order, but it requires additional overhead including an extra database column, so make sure that's really what you want.

Check out the grails manual in the section on GORM: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html